# Notification Message Instantly Fired - Android

Tags: android, time, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm making an app that stores medicines data in an SQLite database in order to send to the user notifications when it's time to take them.
I already created the `BroadcastReceiver` class and managed the notification `Intent`.
The `Calendar.set()` function is called when I add the time (hh:mm:ss) in the database but the problem is that every time I set the time in the `TimePicker` dialog, the notification is sent instantly, at regardless from time.

Here is the `setAlarm` function from the activity where I store the time and the other stuff:

```
public void setAlarm()
{
    String mName = NameFld.getText().toString();
    String mFormat = FormatSpn.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    char[] sTime = TimeBtn.getText().toString().toCharArray();

    if(sTime[0] == '0')
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sTime[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        String tmp = "";
        tmp += sTime[0];
        tmp += sTime[1];

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(tmp);

        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    }

    if(sTime[3] == '0')
    {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sTime[4]);
    }
    else
    {
        String tmp = "";
        tmp += sTime[3];
        tmp += sTime[4];

        int minute = Integer.parseInt(tmp);

        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    }

    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    intent.putExtra("mName", mName);
    intent.putExtra("mFormat", mFormat);

    sendBroadcast(intent);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

The two lines of code below:

```
 String mName = NameFld.getText().toString();
 String mFormat = FormatSpn.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Just takes data from the `EditText` fields then put in an `Intent` to manage them in the notification building.
In order to set the time to the `Calendar` variable, I take the text from the `TimeBtn` button that consists in the time string itself. I just set it when I pick the time from the `TimePicker` dialog.
Then I cast it in a `char` array in order to split hour and minute values and I put them in the `calendar.set()` function, distinguishing if the value starts with 0 to avoid an octal conversion when I cast them to `int`.

Once the time has been set, the `AlarmReceiver` class (extends `BroadcastReceiver`) does the following:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String mName = intent.getStringExtra("mName");
    String mFormat = intent.getStringExtra("mFormat");

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setTicker("It's pill time!");
    builder.setContentTitle(mName);
    builder.setContentText(mFormat);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

There aren't compilation errors, I just can't spot the issue.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
 aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

with

```
 aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
```

Comment: With this changing I got the notification when I just launch the `AddMedicine` activity, and it's shown with no title and content text.

Comment: Where do you want to show the notification in the setAlarm() method or else onReceive() method.

Comment: remove the  sendBroadcast(intent); in the setAlarm() method

Comment: Ok, the problem was the `sendBroadcast(intent)` line, now the notification is fired at the right time. Anyway, without that `sendBroadcast(intent)` I can't send string data to the receiver for the notification building, but I'll invent something. Thank you!

Comment: I've done it, anyway I noticed it doesn't do any difference if I left `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` or `System.currentTimeMillis()+calendar.getTimeInMillis()`.